# 2CHECKOUT ERROR CODE:PE102

Tags: 2checkout

I am currently developing a website that uses the online payment module **2CHECKOUT**. I configured my account in demo mode to test it, and it goes well.

On the contrary, if I cancel the demo mode for my account to accept real payments, I get this error "**ERROR CODE: PE102**" knowing that I have input all my banking information in my profile.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference: http://help.2checkout.com/articles/Knowledge_Article/Error-Code-PE102

Sellers as well as buyers may receive the message ERROR CODE PE102 for several reasons, outlined below:

All Parameter Sets:

Account is not approved to sell.

Account has been closed.

Nonexistent seller, or an invalid value for “sid” or “x_login” was passed in.

Comment: thanks LifeSaver, the account is not approved to sell.                               the problem is solved.